# NSFetchedResultsController inserts lock up the UI

Tags: performance, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a chat application using web-sockets and core-data.

Basically, whenever a message is received on the web-socket, the following happens:

1. check if the message exists by performing a core-data fetch using the id (indexed)
2. if 1. returns yes, update the message and perform a core-data save. if 1. returns no, create the message and perform a core-data save.
3. update table view, by updating or inserting new rows.

**Here's my setup:**

I have 2 default managed-object-contexts. MAIN (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) and WRITER (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType). WRITER has a reference to the persisten store coordinator, MAIN does not, but WRITER is set as MAIN's parent.

TableView is connected to a NSResultsFetchController, connected to MAIN.

Fetches are all performed using temporary contexts ("performBlock:") that have MAIN as their parent. Writes look like this: Save temporary context, then save MAIN, then save WRITER.

**Problem:**

Because the updates come in via web-socket, in a busy chat-room, many updates happen in a short time. Syncs to fetch older messages can mean many messages coming in rapidly. And this locks up the UI.

I track the changes to the ui using fetched-results-controller's delegate like this:

```
// called on main thread
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  NSLog(@"WILL CHANGE CONTENT");
  [_tableView beginUpdates];
}

// called on main thread
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  NSLog(@"DID CHANGE CONTENT");
  [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and here's an example of what I see in the Log-file:

```
2014-07-14 18:46:20.630 AppName[4938:60b] DID CHANGE CONTENT
2014-07-14 18:46:22.334 AppName[4938:60b] WILL CHANGE CONTENT
```

That's almost 2 seconds per insert!

Is it simply a limitation I'm hitting here with tableviews? (I'm talking about 1000+ rows in some cases) But I can't imagine that's the case. UITableViews are super-optimized for that sort of operation.

Any obvious newbie-mistake I might be commiting?

Comment: The time difference shown in your log is the difference between two updates, not the duration of one update.

Comment: @Mundi yes its to show how slow each cycle is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

The problem is `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. The fetches to calculate the height for the rows take time and each time tableView.endUpdates gets called, the UITableView needs the heights for ALL rows.

`tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` is a possible way to go (iOS7+), or I might opt for caching the heights myself (since the rows don't change) or just displaying fewer rows altog

Answer (score 0):

This is not logical:

> Writes look like this: Save temporary context, then save MAIN, then save WRITER.

If writer is a child context of main the changes are not persisted until the *next* save.

Comment: Nono, writer is the parent of main.